# scheme nested recursive functions returning void

Tags: recursion, scheme

Still fighting the urge to not think of programming imperatively, playing around here I have a list of procedures that should be applied to each item in a list and the result of each should be added to a new list (which I refer to as a vector in the code hence the v and vec variables). All I get in the end is a void object.

```
(define (inner-loop proc-i item-list i vec)
      (if (< i (length item-list))
        (begin
            (let ((v (cons (proc-i (list-ref item-list i) vec))))
                (inner-loop proc-i item-list (+ i 1) v)))
        (void)))        

(define (outer-loop proc-list item-list i vec)
  (if (< i (length proc-list))
    (let ((v (cons (inner-loop (list-ref proc-list i) item-list 0 vec) vec)))
        (outer-loop proc-list item-list (+ i 1) v))
    (void)))
```

It's obvious that it's because of the else statements but I don't know how to fix this mostly because I think the way I'm going about it is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, try replacing the `(void)` statements with `vec`. It makes sense, given that that's where you're accumulating the answer. But no, the code doesn't look like idiomatic Scheme - for instance, using `list-ref` is *not* the way to go when traversing a list. Try this instead, it's a more idiomatic way to solve the problem:

```
(define (inner-loop proc-list item-i)
  (if (null? proc-list)
      '()
      (cons ((car proc-list) item-i)
            (inner-loop (cdr proc-list) item-i))))

(define (outer-loop proc-list item-list)
  (if (null? item-list)
      '()
      (append (inner-loop proc-list (car item-list))
              (outer-loop proc-list (cdr item-list)))))
```

You can check that now this:

```
(outer-loop (list sin sqrt sqr) '(1 2 3))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(list (sin 1) (sqrt 1) (sqr 1) (sin 2) (sqrt 2) (sqr 2) (sin 3) (sqrt 3) (sqr 3))
```

Comment: You were correct, replacing (void) with v fixed it. I'm curious to see the better approach. Thank you

Comment: Actually doing that does fix the void problem but yeah it's not correct in logic because it seems to be repeating steps it shouldn't

Comment: This helps me understand a little more but I was trying to do something more like this... proc-list: `(sin sqrt sqr)` item-list: `(1 2 3)` result: `((sin 1) (sqrt 1) (sqr 1) (sin 2) (sqrt 2) (sqr 2) (sin 3) (sqrt 3) (sqr 3))`. Can I do that still using map somehow? hmmm...

Comment: It works! Thank you again! Is there a reason you append in the outer-loop and cons in the inner-loop?...Oh wait I see why. Append is for 2 lists and cons you're adding it to a pair recursively

Comment: that's right. because the output of your function is a list of numbers, not a list of lists. Cons is for adding elements to a list, append for joining together lists.

Comment: It makes so much sense looking at it, hindsight is 20/20. I wouldn't have gotten this at my current level. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! and remember: we use `null?` for checking if a list is empty, `car` for accessing the current element and `cdr` for advancing to the next element - not indexes, `list-ref` - that's not the Scheme way of doing things!

Comment: `list-ref` would be more for querying a list, `car` and `cdr` for traversing it. Correct?

Comment: Absolutely, that's the usual way